# Reemplazar un texto en un archivo txt con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un archivo txt y necesito cambiar todas las palabras que esten escritas por ejemplo (hola) manteniendo todo el formato como esta.

```
<?php

$pagina = file_get_contents('1.txt');


function nombre($cambiar) 
{
   $cambiar = str_replace("hola","buen dia",$cambiar);

return $cambiar; 
}

$nuevoarchivo= nombre($pagina);

?>
```

Hasta ahi me guarda correctamente la variable con el cambio que realiza (str_replace) pero yo necesito que me lo reemplace en el archivo txt. Si alguien me puede ayudar estaria agradecido.

Comment: Puedes hacer algo así: `$oldFile="1.txt"; $newFile="nuevo1.txt";
file_put_contents($newFile,str_replace('hola','buen dia',file_get_contents($oldFile)));` Ahí tendrás en `$newFile` el nuevo archivo con los reemplazos.

Comment: para guardar el archivo tengo que usar esto

$archivo=fopen("1.txt","w+");

fwrite($archivo," $newFile ");

o no es necesario, ¿como lo guardari nuevamente?

Comment: Si quieres reemplazar sobre el mismo archivo puedes hacer esto: `$oldFile="1.txt"; file_put_contents($oldFile,str_replace('hola','buen dia',file_get_contents($oldFile)));` Será tarea tuya establecer código de control, como verificar que al archivo existe, que se puede escribir en él, etc. Esta opción te modificará `1.txt` con el reemplazo y la opción anterior te creará un archivo llamado `nuevo1.txt`. Generalmente el archivo se crea en la ruta donde se ejecutó el script. Si lo quieres en otra ruta se la pones en el nombre del archivo.

Comment: ok, lo voy a provar y cualquier cosa lo molesto nuevamente. muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este propósito puedes hacer uso de [**`file_put_contents()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php) .

### Crear un archivo nuevo con el reemplazo

```
$oldFile="1.txt"; 
$newFile="nuevo1.txt"; 
file_put_contents($newFile,str_replace('hola','buen día',file_get_contents($oldFile)));
```

Este código te crea un nuevo archivo llamado `nuevo1.txt` reemplazando en el contenido la palabra `hola` por la palabra `buen día`.

### Hacer el reemplazo en el archivo viejo

```
$oldFile="1.txt"; 
file_put_contents($oldFile,str_replace('hola','buen día',file_get_contents($oldFile)));
```

Este código reemplazará `hola` por `buen día` en el archivo `1.txt`.

### Nota

Puedes adaptar el que prefieras a tu función. Convendría también poner controles, como revisar si el archivo existe, si está apto para escritura, etc. Eso ya lo dejo a tu cuidado.